# Как совместить FrameLayout и LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

Есть код

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wv" android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="103dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:alpha="000"/>
```

Надо: вместо кнопки Button вставить строку из трех кнопок и сделать строку прозрачной, вместе с прозрачными кнопками.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_menu"
        android:onClick="onClick_Menu"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_style1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_menu3">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_read"
        android:onClick="onClick_read"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_style1"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_qr3"
    ></Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_getPhoto"
        android:onClick="onClick_getPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_style1"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ip_photo4"
        >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

В итоге должен появиться WebView на весь экран и верхней строкой три кнопки наложены на WebView.

Comment: Так подставь весь этот LinearLayout в FrameLayout вместо Button?

Comment: Не получается. AndroidStudio ругается.

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы вам помогли или просто чтобы пожалели, что на вас "наругались". Что это за описание проблемы - она ругается !! Все, чем вам можно помочь по такому описанию проблемы - ругайтесь на нее в ответ тоже, может полегчает :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробовал, все отлично работает, если вставить LinearLayout в FrameLayout вместо Button, вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wv" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_menu"
            android:onClick="onClick_Menu"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="1">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_read"
            android:onClick="onClick_read"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="2"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_getPhoto"
            android:onClick="onClick_getPhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="3">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Работает. Пока не понял почему не сработало до этого, но сейчас все Ок. Благодарю за помощь.